# How can I deploy data grid application?

Tags: ignite

I am developing web application based in Spring. I added Apache ignite in maven dependency.

It is very simple application, which is only 2 rest api.

One is querying by key, which return object. another is put data.

But I have a problem: when I develop additional implementation, I don't know how I can deploy this application.

The application always should be available. but I deploy it to one node, then the node may not available.

Is there good method for distributed memory application deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you will typically start an Ignite server node embedded in your application. You can then start multiple instances of application, and as long as nodes discover each other, they will share the data. For more information about discovery configuration see here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: I meant when I deploy one node(tomcat restarted), then rebalancing is occured. I want to avoid rebalancing. is there any solution about that?

Comment: If you want to have all the data available on each app instance, you need to rebalance it on startup. Why is this an issue for you? Another option is to embed client nodes instead, and have a separate standalone cluster of server nodes. In this case rebalancing would occur only if server topology is changing.

Comment: I think there was a lack of explanation. I meant, There are a number of nodes, and when I deployed one node, it needs to node's restart. so then rebalancing is occured, in that times other nodes get load for rebalancing. I just wanna reducing unnecessary rebalancing. The deployed node just needed restarting not cache loss. So one guys tell me [base line topology](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/IEP-4+Baseline+topology+for+caches), I think it is exactly I want.

Comment: Got it, makes sense.